# Iterating through CSV leaking memory

Tags: python, csv, memory

I have this function that takes a CSV file on the disk, opens it using a `csv.DictReader` object, deletes three keys, deletes the file from disk and then returns the data:

```
def process_data(self, filename):
    results = []
    with open(filename) as f:
        data = csv.DictReader(f)
        for row in data:
            del row['foo']
            del row['bar']
            del row['spot']
            results.append(row)
    os.remove(filename)
    return results
```

I'm calling this function sequentially (within the same process) 60 times to process 60 CSV files. Around 20 files in the process crashes without error, and after some investigation I've found that memory usage is increasing each time this function is called until memory is exhausted and the system kills the process.

I've used `tracemalloc` to display the files allocating the most memory and it seems that each time `process_data` is called the csv library allocates about 800MB of memory and it isn't cleared properly between each call.

```
snapshot = tracemalloc.take_snapshot()
top_stats = snapshot.statistics('lineno')
for stat in top_stats[:10]:
     print(stat)
```

outputs as first two lines (following 8 don't allocate more than 2MB)

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/csv.py:120: size=619 MiB, count=7578695, average=86 B
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/csv.py:112: size=214 MiB, count=3404479, average=66 B
```

Looking at `csv.py` these two lines are part of the `DictReader` class. Line 112 increments the reader to the next row and line 120 creates an `OrderedDict` from the data.

After each function call I've iterated through every object returned by `globals()` and `locals()` to check the size and there don't seem to be any large objects, nor is there an unexpectedly high number of objects.

I can't determine why this is causing a memory leak in my application. My expectation is that the `DictReader` object should be cleared once the file is closed (which should happen as the function ends as I'm using `with open`) but it seems that memory is being used and never cleared while getting the data from the CSV.

Comment: You `return` the DictReader object that you created. Why? It looks like it's been exhausted anyway.

Comment: Eek, no. I modified the code sample slightly to make it 'cleaner' for SO but screwed up the logic. I've edited it now. Thanks for calling attention to it!

Comment: My understanding is that it should be closed automagically at the end of the `with` block.

Comment: You're right; it's supposed to do that. Just as a matter of killing off this faint qualm, does putting `f.close()` after the `with` block make any difference?

Comment: The file should be closed on `return`. But perhaps the garbage collector is taking its time to clear the memory. You can try forcing garbage collection with [`gc.collect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#gc.collect).

Comment: I think your use of the `tracemalloc` module is misleading — all you're doing is seeing were memory is being allocated. What matters with respect to memory leaks is how much of it is not deallocated (freed). Suggest you take another look at documentation in the module's documentation. Your function is creating and returning a `results` list, which I'm guessing you're accumulating during the processing of the 60 files — that's the most likely cause of the memory problem IMO. In other words, I don't think there's a leak at all.

Comment: It's a fair point about tracemalloc only showing allocation but if memory usage is increasing unexpectedly then seeing where it's being allocated is a sensible place to look, I think. You're right that the results are aggregated - I've checked the size of the list after each function call though and it's only around 1.5GB before the process crashes. The system I'm using has 10GB memory available.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to keep in mind is that python doesn't gives back memory to os even when the code isn't referencing the particular memory anymore So i suggest you to add
`gc.collect()`
After each function call to process_data()

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with the csv.DictReader, but if it reads the whole file in memory, this will stream the data into a list. still quite memory consumptious if the csv gets large.

```
def process_data(self, filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        csv_sep = ','
        header = f.readline().strip()
        results = []
        for line in f:
            data = dict(zip(header.split(csv_sep), line.strip().split(csv_sep)))
            data.pop('foo')
            data.pop('bar')
            data.pop('spot')
            results.append(data)
    os.remove(filename)
    return results
```